# How to keep sets of numbers in multiple arrays and print max using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a single column of numbers where each set is separated by say blank line.

```
5    
6
10   
4

3    
4

34  
5435
545
543
3
3

0 
0
4343
```

Now I want to find max value from each set (between blank lines) and do further operation. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$ awk '{n=n>$1?n:$1}/^$/{print n;n=""}END{print n}' file
10
4
5435
4343
```

You would just change the `print n` statements with whatever your *further operations* are.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I had to do more changes on my side for specific problem but this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

with GNU awk you can work in paragraph mode

```
awk -v RS= '{x=-inf; n=split($0, a, "\n"); 
for(i=0; i<=n; ++i)x=a[i]>x?a[i]:x; print x}' file
10
4
5435
4343
```

Comment: There's nothing GNU awk specific about that approach, it'll work with any modern awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v RS= -F'\n' '{
    min = max = $1
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        min = ($i < min ? $i : min)
        max = ($i > max ? $i : max)
    }
    print min, max
} ' file
4 10
3 4
3 5435
0 4343
```